# Exporting typescript type definitions

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my project I'd like to have one file with all the *typescript* definitions like so:

*type_defs.tsx*:

```
interface T_oauth_obj {
    oauth_callback: string,
    oauth_consumer_key: string,
    oauth_nonce: string,
    oauth_signature_method: string,
    oauth_timestamp: string,
    oauth_version: number,
    oauth_signature: string,
}

interface IAuthRequests {
    getRequestToken: () => string
    Authorize(): void
    getAccessToken(): void  
}
...
```

The problem is that when i try to export the typedefs like so:

```
export {IAuthRequests, T_oauth_obj}
```

I get the error:

```
Re-exporting a type when the '--isolatedModules'...
```

As I've found in the net there can be only the default export for a typedef file that means that i have to prepare one file per type definition which is absolutely an absurd!

In my opinion the constraint not allowing to have multiple, non-default exports for typedefs is totally nonsense and making the coding redundant and hard to re-use. Having one file with all the typedefs can help having more tidy and debug-able code.

P.S

Is there a way to achieve the goal I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
export interface T_oauth_obj {
    oauth_callback: string,
    oauth_consumer_key: string,
    oauth_nonce: string,
    oauth_signature_method: string,
    oauth_timestamp: string,
    oauth_version: number,
    oauth_signature: string,
}

export interface IAuthRequests {
    getRequestToken: () => string
    Authorize(): void
    getAccessToken(): void  
}
```

and then import:

```
import { T_oauth_obj, IAuthRequests } from "your.file"
```

Comment: Thx - that works but WHY cant i use the `export {IAuthRequests, T_oauth_obj}` syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Your exported types can either be named, or each file can have one default type export. The `export` keyword simply does not allow for exporting multiple values.

So, since it only works for one value or type at a time, this won't work because `{IAuthRequests, T_oauth_obj}` is not a valid single type.

You could do a default export of a whole type, but this is probably not what you want:

```
export default { req: IAuthRequests, oauth: T_oauth_obj }
```

Or you could do:

```
export interface IAuthRequests { ... }
export interface T_oauth_obj { ... }
```

If you want one `export` keyword to export multiple named types, then I have no other help than to say it *just doesn't do that*. To answer why you'll probably have to ask the typescript maintainers. The answer is likely to be a deliberate design choice to more closely match how `export` works is plain JS.